# c# Razor post array of keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, razor, key-value

I need to pass an array of KeyValuePair from a Razor form via post to a C# controller.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class OperatorViewModel
{
    public class EntityFields
    {
        ...

        public KeyValuePair<string, int?>[] VariablesValue { get; set; }

    }

    public EntityFields Fields { get; }

    ...
}
```

**Razor View:**

```
        <table class="Workloads-Options-Popup-Table" data-ref="VariablesValue">
            @for (int index = 0; index < Model.Fields.VariablesValue.Count(); index++)
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, string> item = variablesValue.ElementAt(index);

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @(Html.CustomHTMLHelper().TextInput(new {
                            name = $"Fields.VariablesValue[{index}].Key",
                            value = item.Key,
                        }))
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @(Html.CustomHTMLHelper().IntegerInput(new {
                            name = $"Fields.VariablesValue[{index}].Value",
                            value = item.Value,
                        }))
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

On controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostUpdateOperatorOptions(OperatorViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ...
    }
```

The viewModel.Fields.VariablesValue contains the right number of rows but each row contains both, Key and Value, to null.

If I use a Dictionary<string, int> it work proper but I need to have both, Key and Value, nullable so I'm trying to sort out it using a array of KeyValuePair<string, int?>.

*NOTE: CustomHTMLHelper is just an HTML helper that produce a input field with some contraints about the type of input requested.*

Thanks

Comment: Can you show  your get action where you create  a view model too pls

Comment: Model.Fields.VariablesValue = new KeyValuePair<string, int?>[] {
            new KeyValuePair<string, int?>(),
        };

At the first run the list contains one empty item. Anyway if I use Dictionary it work proper so I think is just a binding problem.

Comment: I am sory, but what you posted is looking very strange. You to post the real code that could be compiled.

Comment: I think that the GET function is not important. The inputs are generated inside the Razor View and the name that input have is something like Fields.VariablesValue[0].Key/Fields.VariablesValue[0].Value, Fields.VariablesValue[1].Key/Fields.VariablesValue[1].Value,
and so on but what coming inside the POST is alway [null, null], [null, null] and so on.

Comment: Just do you have some example online where someone pass a array of KeyValuePair to a controller? Because I not able to find example about this case.

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution.
Instead using a KeyValuePair array I created an array of custom class and now all work proper.

```
public class OperatorViewModel : ModalViewModel
{
    public class VariableValue {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public int? Value { get; set; }
    }


    public class EntityFields
    {
    ...

        public IEnumerable<VariableValue> VariablesValue { get; set; }
    }

    public EntityFields Fields { get; }

    ...

}
```